# PowerShell version upgrade from 2.0 is reverted after reboot

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

PowerShell upgrade on Windows 2008 R2 (from 2.0 to 3.0) successfully installed, but reverted after reboot.
Same behavior for upgrade from 2.0 to 4.0 and 2.0 to 5.0.

Couldn't find the possible cause.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you "upgrading" PowerShell?

Comment: By installing WMF 3.0 (Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu).
This got success in many servers, only 3 servers are having this problem.